# Overwriting existing table with Jenkins, InfluxDB plugin

Tags: jenkins, influxdb

I can specify tables and fill them with data, but I don't know how to overwrite existing fields.

I'm using the InfluxDB plugin using the following code to send data to a specific table in the influx database, as per [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/influxdb/):

```
def myFields1 = [:]
def myFields2 = [:]
def myCustomMeasurementFields = [:]
myFields1['field_a'] = 11
myFields1['field_b'] = 12
myFields2['field_c'] = 21
myFields2['field_d'] = 22
myCustomMeasurementFields['series_1'] = myFields1
myCustomMeasurementFields['series_2'] = myFields2
myTags = ['series_1':['tag_a':'a','tag_b':'b'],'series_2':['tag_c':'c','tag_d':'d']]
influxDbPublisher(selectedTarget: 'my-target', customDataMap: myCustomMeasurementFields, customDataMapTags: myTags)
```

So I can define fields, assign values, assign them to tables (series_1,series_2). But how can I overwrite existing fields in a table that already exists? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to overwrite values in InfluxDB.
Value field which you write into InfluxDB can vary from original data only by its value. No difference with tag keys, measurement name and timestamp can be made. If you write new value as I described, it will automatically overwrite value you had there before.
In other cases you need to delete old data and then write new values or just accept existing old data and use filtering possibilities of InfluxDB.
By the way. Thinking about InfluxDB as table data generates problems like yours. My advice is to think about it as an indexed time series database ( it is truly time series database).